# .each (generate dropdown from html element, replace element)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help.
I have some data in the divs. I managed to extract data from each div and from them make dropdown's.
Now, certain element (class .change in the example) should be replaced with those dropdown's and there I got tangled up in .each function. How to solve it?

```
// convert data from div to dropdown
$('.wrap').each(function () {
    var $select = $('<select />');
    $(this).find('.answer').each(function () {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).next().html()).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });

    $(this).replaceWith($select);

    // replace .change with dropdown
    $(".change").each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($select);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shinzon/jgj6whmx/

Comment: You can fool SO, but not it's users. You should put the relevant code in your question as well.

Comment: @Vohuman your wish is OP's command, actually I think he added the code before the comment was posted

Comment: @Huangism :), the question was updated by user SpYk3HH, as far as I can see.

Comment: [***is this what you're trying to achieve?***](http://jsfiddle.net/ruufvv45/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to fill each `.change` with the created dropdown for each  `.wrap`, while you only want to change the next one in line.

```
// convert data from div to dropdown
$('.wrap').each(function () {
    var $select = $('<select />');
    $(this).find('.answer').each(function () {
        var $option = $('<option />');
        $option.attr('value', $(this).next().html()).html($(this).html());
        $select.append($option);
    });

    // remove old unneeded div
    $(this).remove();

    // replace first .change with dropdown
    $(".change:first").replaceWith($select);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgj6whmx/5/